# Heap Data-Structure Re-Heap Method

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm working on my assignment, which is to read from a text file, store the first 10 words in a heap. Then continue to read from the text file and if the word is less than the root of the heap, to replace it and re-heap the entire heap. My code seems to be working for the most part however I am running into a few problems.

- Some words even though they are less than the root are not being swapped
- Duplicate words

I am supposed to end up with a heap containing the words `abandoning abandons
abased
abash
abashed
abashes
abasing
abate
abatement
abbe`

However I get the words, `abashes
                abashed                              abash
        abased              abandons              abandoning              bewilderedly
    abandoning      armful      abandoning`

---

Here is my code so far:

```
public static void readFile() {
    BufferedReader reader;
    String inputLine;
    int counter = 0;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(".\\src\\dictionary.txt"));
        while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(counter < 10) {
                heap.insert(inputLine);
                counter++;
            }

            if(inputLine.compareTo(heap.find(0)) < 0) {
                heap.change(0, inputLine);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}

public boolean insert(String value) {
    if(currentSize == maxSize) { return false; }

    Node newNode = new Node(value);
    heap[currentSize] = newNode;
    trickleUp(currentSize++);
    return true;
}

public void trickleUp(int index) {
    int parent = (index - 1) / 2;
    Node bottom = heap[index];

    while(index > 0 && heap[parent].getData().compareTo(bottom.getData()) < 0) {
        heap[index] = heap[parent];
        index = parent;
        parent = (parent - 1) / 2;
    }
    heap[index] = bottom;
}

public void trickleDown(int index) {
    int largerChild;
    Node top = heap[index];

    while(index < currentSize / 2) {
        int leftChild = 2 * index + 1;
        int rightChild = index + 1;

        if(rightChild < currentSize && heap[leftChild].getData().compareTo(heap[rightChild].getData()) < 0) {
            largerChild = rightChild;
        } else {
            largerChild = leftChild;
        }

        if(top.getData().compareTo(heap[largerChild].getData()) > 0) {
            break;
        }

        heap[index] = heap[largerChild];
        index = largerChild;
    }
    heap[index] = top;
}

public boolean change(int index, String newValue) {
    if(index < 0 || index >= currentSize) { return false; }

    String oldValue = heap[index].getData();
    heap[index].setData(newValue);

    if(oldValue.compareTo(newValue) < 0) {
        trickleUp(index);
    } else {
        trickleDown(index);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what have you already done yourself concerning the problem?

Comment: on a quick side note, is this an assignment? Because if it is not: heapsorting is only faster than mergesort if there is a continuous addition of elements. If you have to sort the elements just once, a mergesort (or quicksort) would be more efficiënt.

Comment: Have you run it step-by-step under debugger (assuming you use Eclipse or other IDE)?

Comment: or intermediate steps showing how the heap is being built

Comment: @bas Yes, this is for an assignment.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, but I only got partially through it, the text file contains 30,000 lines.

Comment: but you can test it with these 10 words.

Comment: trickleDown() method has very suspicious rightChild initialization (misses multiplication by 2 at the very least)

Comment: As @OlegEstekhin said, `int rightChild = index + 1;` should have been `int rightChild = leftChild + 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get binary tree if you use such indexing:

```
    int leftChild = 2 * index + 1;
    int rightChild = index + 1;
```

I think you meant to write this:

```
    int leftChild = 2 * index + 1;
    int rightChild = 2 * index + 2;
```

So the tree will look like this

```
       0
     /   \
    1     2
   / \   / \
  3   4 5   6 
 / \
7   8 ... and so on
```

As for duplicate elements as far as I know heap can contain duplicates and does not support duplicate removal. For example this is a valid heap of numbers

```
      10
    /    \
   9      8
  / \    / \
 5   7  7   6
```